# Cannot rewrite ConfigurablePriceResolver in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

I try to rewrite the `ConfigurablePriceResolver` in Magento 2, but without success. In my `di.xml` I have the following:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver"
        type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver"/>
</config>
```

But my class doesn't seem to get picked up. Anyone knows what might be going wrong here? I try to create a temporary fix for my client for https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4314.

I can rewrite other classes like this, but for some reason this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also looking for it